# Get date format of current site which is set in regional settings using JSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, jsom, date-time

I need date format of site,
I can get date separator using `get_regionalSettings()` and `get_dateSeparator()` .

I tried `get_dateFormat()` but it returns "1".

I need to know date format of particular site "dd/mm/yyyy" , "mm/dd/yyyy" or whatever the default date time format is set in SharePoint site.

How can I get that using JSOM?

Comment: I'm not sure actually, never used `_api/web/RegionalSettings/dateFormat`. But it return 0 from webs with locale US (mmddyyyy)and 1 from my web with Norwegian (ddmmyyyy). You could check if 1 is ddmmyyyy and vice versa.

Comment: @AndersAune I think there are more formats than ddmmyyyy and mmddyyy, so it won't work, and also what about date separators?

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to figure out what time zone it is displaying. There are two types of Regional Settings that specify the time zone:

- Regional Settings in User Profile Settings
- Regional Settings under each site

**May b try this link** [How to Get the Time Zone in SharePoint Online Using JSOM](http://blogs.perficient.com/delivery/blog/2016/03/30/how-to-get-time-zone-in-sharepoint-online-using-jsom/)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue in my SPFX webpart. I was trying to show date format based on regional settings of current site.

So at first I take current culture name. Culture name can be like "en-US", "nn-NO" etc. Then I use moment to format the date. Check below example:

```
const currentCultureName = props.context.pageContext.legacyPageContext.currentCultureName;
moment.locale(currentCultureName);
const dateString = moment(new Date()).format('L');
```

---

*If the answer is helpful, please upvote.*

Answer (score -1):

Add a reference to moment js. This can be downloaded from https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js .

And add below code in your client context code.

```
 var dt = oListItem.get_item('datelistcolumnname');if (dt != null) { alert(moment(dt).format('L')); }
```

Comment: I want to get the date format of particular site, are you sure you are answering my question.